# MySQL Between advise

Tags: android-sqlite

I made this query:

```
SELECT * FROM appointment WHERE day BETWEEN 1 AND 25 ORDER BY hour
```

It's return me all appointments of all days, is not bad but I need only 1 result per day.

So, I don't need "count(*) day 1, day 2, day 3..." because I need all information from this appointment.

If day 1 have 5 results, I need only one (and any) result of this day.
If day 2 have 1 result, ok, give me this one.
If day 3 have nothing, ok too
...
If day 25 have 9 results, I need only one (any) result.

Comment: What is the meaning of the `day` column?

Comment: Why aren't you storing date and time values with a single `datetime` value? Are you really storing each component (year, month, day, hour, minute) in separate columns?

Comment: See the duplicate question, and use one of those techniques to select the first or last row in each `GROUP BY day`.